java.io VS java.nio when using Virtual Threads in Java 21
I am thoroughly learning Spring Boot and I am learning how to upload files and in my example I will be storing the path in the database and the contents in the file system outside of what is publicly accessible.
But very soon I am going to be building my own network module including a server side framework from scratch. I am going to build my own TCP, UDP, HTTP servers, and it will be with Virtual threads with Java21 as a min requirement.
I know I would be using Sockets from the .net package, but I could also use the nio for the server.
I expect this is more of a general question, but if there are certain details about Spring Boot that make it relevant i would like to know.
From what I am aware off about Virtual Threads is that we can easily write normal blocking code and the JVM suspends the virtual threads when it encounters blocking code.
With this in mind, if I am using virtual threads and I wanted to work with the file system, should I be using the regular blocking java.io file classes or still use the java.nio ?
Is it true that the NIO package provides more capabilities as far as checking and setting file permissions ?
I am learning the old java.io anyway, but i can always shift to NIO if needed

The Networking section could be a good reference to start with, though the decision over nio vs io shall still remain agnostic of whether virtual threads are being used in the underlying implementation or not. Yet seemingly the bias would be towards nio considering the limitations it has already evolved over. Further considering this and this references for the use case mentioned
